# CodeIgniter 3 not calling default controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have been asked to look into an issue where the default_controller in a CodeIgniter 3 project does not seem to be called. Instead we are seeing a 404 error.

In the `application/controllers` folder there is a `Welcome.php` file with the following content:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                // Your own constructor code
        }

        public function index()
        {
                print('hello');
                $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }
}
```

The `application/config/routes.php` file has:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

I only see a 404 and none of the expected text.

Adding a `print` statement to the `routes.php` shows that it is being loaded. Also, tying it explicitly to a route has it called, but not when it is set to be the default controller.

```
$route['blah'] = "welcome"
```

Can anyone suggest what may be going on?

BTW We are using PHP7 on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Comment: what about your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: What about it? What should I check?

Comment: use `localhost/project_name/welcome`.Any error?

Comment: @AndreM any update ? solved ?

Comment: @AndreM If it has none of the standard rules that CI is expecting, i.e. Rewrite to index.php, then this will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the project was an upgrade from a CodeIgniter 2 project and there were some migration steps that hadn't quite been completed. It turned out that there was a MY_Router.php in the libraries folder, that seemed to be throwing things off - at least moving it into applications/core solved the issue.

An additional modification was needed in the MY_Router.php file given the capitalization of the filenames, requested as part of the CI3 migration:

```
function _validate_request($segments)
{
    // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.ucfirst($segments[0]).'.php'))
    {
        return $segments;
    }
    ...
}
```

BTW I was sure it wasn't a HTTP server rewrite issue, since a CodeIgniter 404 error page was showing the expected call path. I had added a `print(_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` to see what was going on.

Edit: I now see that ucfirst approach above is not ideal in other installations, but given that there are no subfolders in this project's controllers folder, it is a quick fix for this project.